# Different layouts for different screen's width

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage, and I want to use JavaScript to center some text (contained in a "p" with the display:inline-block attribute) when the text is shifted under everything else (on a smaller window). When the window size is big enough, I have the text on the right of the screen (where I want it for larger windows).

Basically, I have content on the left and right of the screen for bigger windows, but I want that content to become centered and vertical when the browser is smaller.

I've tried using .addEventListener() but my JavaScript knowledge is pretty limited.

Any thoughts? Does this make sense?

Comment: To clarify what you are trying to achieve: let's call the left content 'A', and the right content 'B'. If the users screen width is narrow, you want 'A' on top and 'B' below 'A'?

Comment: Yes, but I also want A and B centered horizontally when they are on top of each other (when the screen is narrow).

Comment: The topic „how to set layout according on screen size“ is one of the most discussed topics over the last five years and you seem to have missed that completely. Please get into that topic through using a search engine and reading introductory blogs. Big hint: Search for „CSS media queries“

Comment: yikes, sorry! I'm new to this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're trying to do some sort of responsive design. You're better off doing this without any javascript.

You should look into [Css Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), that are meant to set specific css styles depending on the screen size:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
```

Similar to your scenario, here's a sample showing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/xkJ3G/

Resize the window and test it!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired effect using only HTML and CSS.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vn93/)

### HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.outer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.A, 
div.B {
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Linebreak will be when width is lesser than min-width (in this example when 40% < 250px)